# reading a configuration information only once in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm using the ConfigParser to read the configuration information stored in a file. I'm able to read the content and use it across other modules in the project. I'm not sure if the configuration file is read every time I call config.get(parameters). How can I make sure that the configuration information is read only once and rest of the time its read from the cache.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of ConfigParser to see what it does?

Answer (score 2):

I would try assigning the configuration to a variable.

```
configVariable = config.get(parameters)
```

Then you can pass the configuration variable to other modules as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of the ConfigParser class reads its data only once.